# Неверное завершение SQL-предложения

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Есть запрос `SELECT * FROM SMSPECREFUSE WHERE REASON= 'Недопоставка'`
Он работает верно и выводит, то что нужно. 
Если добавляю в запрос SELECT * FROM SMSPECREFUSE WHERE REASON= 'Недопоставка', 'Превышение заявки', 'Несоответствие цены', 'Нет в заявке', 'Брак', 'Обмен товара', 'Короткий срок', 'Невыполнение заказов', 'Нетоварный вид'
в конце выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM SMSPECREFUSE WHERE REASON IN (
  'Недопоставка', 'Превышение заявки', 'Несоответствие цены', 
  'Нет в заявке', 'Брак', 'Обмен товара', 'Короткий срок', 
  'Невыполнение заказов', 'Нетоварный вид'
)
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM SMSPECREFUSE WHERE 
  REASON = 'Недопоставка' OR
  REASON = 'Превышение заявки' OR
  ...
```

Comment: 2 вариант то что нужно

Comment: @ИльяЕвтропов Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Да , написано через 6 минут, поставлю обязательно)